# Latest FreeSWITCH versions have problems with conferences

Tags: freeswitch

We have issues with FreeSWITCH 1.10.1 dealing with multiple participants in conferences. Randomly we get a lot of disturbing noise that disappears after a few seconds or even minutes.

We did a lot of tests with up to 16 clients and the only setup where we never did get this disturbing noise was with an older version of FreeSWITCH (v1.5.1).

We used the same configuration for both FreeSWITCH versions.

This is what we found out:

- it seems not to be a general resource issue: all the time the throughput was < 1 Mbit + the CPU load < 15 %
- it seems not to be related to transcoding: using only PCMA appeared to be slightly better than using only GSM or PCMA+GSM
- it is an issue of the used FreeSWITCH version: 1.5.1 had no audio quality issues, even after > 7 minutes, 1.10.1 sometimes starts with good quality, sometimes already starts with bad quality and always creates this disturbing noise after a while
- it is only related to conferences and not to FreeSWITCH in general: when we did in parallel a conference and a single call, only the conference had the issues, the single call was always ok
- run FreeSWITCH directly on a physical computer or on a virtual machine seems to make no difference
- run FreeSWITCH as a Windows service has no effect
- set process priority to 'realtime' may have improved it, but we still had issues

These are the FreeSWITCH versions that were tested:

- C 2013  1.5.1b x86/win32 Release
- C 2019  1.10.1 x64 Release
- C 2023  1.10.10 x64 Release (did only do a short test to verify that it has the same issues as 1.10.1)

Here is our conferences.conf:

```
<configuration name="conference.conf">
  <caller-controls>
    <group name="default">
      <control action="hangup" digits="#"/>
    </group>
  </caller-controls>
  <profiles>
    <profile name="default">
      <param name="domain" value="$${domain}"/>
      <param name="rate" value="8000"/>
      <param name="interval" value="20"/>
      <param name="energy-level" value="20"/>
      <param name="auto-record" value="$${recordings_dir_conferences}/${strftime(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)}-${conference_name}-${sip_to_user}-${vehiclePhoneNumber}-${uuid}.wav"/>
    </profile> 
  </profiles>
</configuration>
```

Do you have an idea if conferences with multiple participants (we tested with 16 softphones, but in productive environments we will have much more) behave different in newer versions of FreeSWITCH? Is there some setting that has to be configured to make this work in newer FreeSWITCH versions?